# Getting data from firebase in array in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. I have following data in firebase:
[image]

Inside EventPlayer I have array of data for key eventID. I want to get all objects for a eventID in an Array.

My code:

```
final String eventId=intent.getStringExtra("EventID");
    mref.child("EventPlayer").child(eventId).orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId);
    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                EventRequest post = child.getValue(EventRequest.class);
                if(post != null){
                    System.out.println(post);
                    arrPlayers.add(post);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

The post has no value and it is an empty class.

### Edit

Code for creating arrraylist:

```
arrPlayers = new ArrayList<EventRequest>();
```

Comment: you are using arrPlayers outside the onDataChange ?

Comment: HI Bruno, I need to get this class in my arrPlayers and populate listview with it

Comment: can you post the full code of class and the code to populate listview.

Comment: Code is complete, I haven't written code to populate listview yet

Comment: I have added how I am creating arraylist

Comment: Nothing in your code ties the array to the list view yet. You'll need a list adapter for that. If you already created an adapter, an educated guess is that you forgot to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.  The only change is in the first few lines, with the postQuery variable.

```
final String eventId=intent.getStringExtra("EventID");
Query postQuery = mref.child("EventPlayer").child(eventId).orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId);
    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    postQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                EventRequest post = child.getValue(EventRequest.class);
                if(post != null){
                    System.out.println(post);
                    arrPlayers.add(post);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

Your second line of code creates a `Query` object, but you never assign it to anything.  Assigning it to a new variable and then adding the `ValueEventListener` to that new variable should get you to your data.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I am just wondering why it didn't work without Query.

Comment: Your original code added the `ValueEventListener` to a reference that pointed to the root of the database structure.  That is not where your data was, so your `getValue()` call did not return the data you expected.  My change saves off the Query object that points to the specific data that you want, then attaches the `ValueEventListener` to that query so that `getValue()` returns the data you expect.

Comment: Ohh yes I got it now, Thanks for the help Scott

Answer (score 0):

To get all those event ids, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventIdRef = rootRef.child("EventPlayer").child(eventId);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String eventID = ds.child("eventID").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(eventID);
            Log.d("TAG", eventID);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
eventIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```